# Shell: sed pipeline

Tags: sed, pipe, tee

I'm trying to make a script that redirects data from a serial port to other one.
I have realizate it using this command:

```
cat /dev/ttyS0 > /dev/ttyS1
```

Everything works but, now I would also logging data. I thought I'd use the `tee` command:

```
cat /dev/ttyS0 | tee /dev/ttyS1 log.txt
```

Now I want to make sure that every time it is recorded on the log file should be preceded by the string `"from S0 to S1:"` I tried this:

```
cat /dev/ttyS0 | tee /dev/ttyS1 | sed 's/$/from S0 to S1/' | less > log.txt
```

But it does not work, the file remains empty.
Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nitpick: looks like a useless use of cat; better: `tee /dev/ttyS1 < /dev/ttyS0`.

Comment: Are you sure there's never anything in log.txt? Note that pipes usually buffer I/O anywhere from 1kB to several kB. If that's the case, you need to be more patient.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
cat /dev/ttyS0 | tee /dev/ttyS1 | sed 's/^/from S0 to S1: /' | tee log.txt
```

Since you wanted to *prefix* the line with the string, the `$` in your `sed` has been replaced by `^`.  The substituted output is sent to `STDOUT` that can serve as an input for `tee`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but I'd remove the pager from the pipeline and redirect the `sed` output directly to the file. Also, if you want to prepend text you need to match the beginning of a line (`^`) not the end of a line (`$`).

```
... | sed 's/^/from S0 to S1: /' > log.txt
```

Also, what does the input look like in the first place? Does it contain linebreaks that the pattern could match?